# UserPrincipal ExtensionSet not working for multivalue attribute

Tags: c#

I am extending UserPrincipal (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384372(VS.90).aspx)  to obtain attributes which are not provided by it. It is working great for values like Company, Department and others but I have found a problem with ProxyAddresses. It is not working.
I have tried exact copy for HomePhoneOther and it is not working too.
I have found that it is working only if collection contains only one element otherwise old values are kept and new values are added to them.

Does anyone faced the same problem? Currently I do not know how to set HomePhoneOther if I have more then one value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found that you have to clear the values first before you add new ones.

In your extension class:

```
[DirectoryProperty("ProxyAddresses")]
public string[] ProxyAddresses
{
    get
    {
        object[] proxysRaw = ExtensionGet("ProxyAddresses");
        string[] proxys = new string[proxysRaw.Length];

        for (int x = 0; x < proxysRaw.Length; x++)
        {
            proxys[x] = (string)proxysRaw[x];
        }

        return proxys;
    }
    set
    {
        ExtensionSet("ProxyAddresses", value);
    }
}
```

Clear the values and set the new ones:

```
string[] s = new string[2];
s[0] = "smtp:jdoe@hotmail.com";
s[1] = "smtp:john.doe@hotmail.com";
user.ProxyAddresses = null;
user.Save();
user.ProxyAddresses = s;
user.Save();
```